# When $\int_a^b\left(f(x)\right)^kdx=\left[\int_a^bf(x)dx\right]^k$

Tags: calculus, inequality, integral-inequality

Under what conditions on $f(x)$ the following equation holds?
$$\int_a^b\left(f(x)\right)^kdx=\left[\int_a^bf(x)dx\right]^k$$
with $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\gt1$.
I know the following inequality holds:
$$\int_a^b\left(f(x)\right)^kdx\ge\left[\int_a^bf(x)dx\right]^{k-1}$$
when:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\ge(b-a)^{k-1}$$
but is it possible from this last two inequalities say something about the first one?
Thanks.

Comment: After rescaling, you are basically asking about when Jensen's inequality is an equality.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $[F(b)-F(a)]^{k-1}$?

Comment: Negativity is an issue, here. If $f$ takes values in $\{-1,+1\}$, $\mu(\{x:f(x)=1\})=\mu(\{x:f(x)=-1\})$ and $k$ is odd, equality holds for sure.

Comment: It seems the equality needs rescaling, because even for a constant function $f(x)\equiv c$ we have $c^k(b-a)=\int_a^b c^kdx =\int_a^b\left(f(x)\right)^kdx=\left[\int_a^bf(x)dx\right]^k=[c(b-a)]^k$.